# How can I add animations to my images in my Django app?

Tags: html, css, django

I´m trying to add a kind of animation to some images in my Django app, what I want to do is that when the user moves the mouse around the image it gets bigger.

I tried adding some code in my CSS but the image won't change

Thank you for your help.

My index.html

```html
    {%block contenido %}

    <div id="container" class="foto_pelicula">
     {% for p in peliculas %}
      {% if p.genero.id == 1 %}
      <a href="{% url 'detallesPelicula' p.id %}"><img src={{p.urlPortada}} width="289" height="289"/></a></li>
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <div id="container" class="foto_pelicula">
     {% for p in peliculas %}
     {% if p.genero.id == 2 %}
     <a href="{% url 'detallesPelicula' p.id %}"><img src={{p.urlPortada}} width="289" height="289"/></a></li>
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <div id="container" class="foto_pelicula">
     {% for p in peliculas %}
      {% if p.genero.id == 3 %}
      <a href="{% url 'detallesPelicula' p.id %}"><img src={{p.urlPortada}} width="289" height="289"/></a></li>
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

The Images SRCs are urls that I take from the internet, I guess it does not really matter whether they are taken from the internet or stored in your proyect.

my CSS

```css
#container{ 
       width: 290px;
       overflow: hidden;
       margin: 5px 4px 0 auto;
       padding: 0;
       background: #222; /* FONDO DEL RECTANGULO CONTENEDOR */
       border: 3px solid #8E1600;
       float: left;
}
```

I added this new lines to my CSS but the image won't change.

```css
.foto_pelicula > img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
 }
```

Maybe I'm not using the proper lines in the CSS as I'm a junior programmer.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has no connection to Django. In future try to create working html template for your purposes and then add it to django template.

You setup `.foto_pelicula > img:hover` to transform image. But `>` selector finds only direct child. See [documentation on selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

And in your code direct child is `a`, but not `img`. Therefore you don't see result. You can change your css rule to `.foto_pelicula > a > img:hover`

See demo:

```css
#container{ 
       width: 290px;
       overflow: hidden;
       margin: 5px 4px 0 auto;
       padding: 0;
       background: #222; /* FONDO DEL RECTANGULO CONTENEDOR */
       border: 3px solid #8E1600;
       float: left;
} 

.foto_pelicula > a > img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
 }
```

```html
<div id="container" class="foto_pelicula">
<a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/289" width="289" height="289"/></a>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT**

In your html code I see several divs with `id="container"`. You can setup only one id with certain name to each page. That's why it called [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

So change your ids to classes or give different id names for this divs.